WhatsApp web: "Your computer does not have enough space for WhatsApp to run. Please create more storage..."
I'm viewing web.whatsapp.com in Opera on Linux.  Every few hours I get the following message:

I have more than enough disk space, and the usage is only about 50MB:

My web searching shows no resolution.  If I ignore the message and reload the page, everything works fine again (for a while).
How can I get rid of this message permanently?

Did you activate memory saving in inactive tabs? I have the same problem since I did in my Chromium settings.
